how to let pip install show progress
In the past, I install my personal package with setup.py:
python setup.py install

Now this method is deprecated, and I can only use pip:
python -m pip install . 

However, the method with setup.py can show install messages, but pip method cannot.
For example, when there is c++ code which requires compiling the source code, the setup.pymethod can print warnings to the screen, but thepip` method only let you wait until everything is done.
Is there any method that I can see more messages with pip like the setup.py in the past?

Try pip install -v, -vv, -vvv.

@phd Thanks!! Would you please add an answer, so that I can accept it?

You can force pip to be more verbose using pip -v install. The option  is additive, and can be used up to 3 times to increase verbosity:
pip -v install
pip -vv install
pip -vvv install

